# How do I print SQL query using MessageBox in C#

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I am stuck with this problem since yesterday. I have created a button, which when clicked display the results from a SQL Server table. I thought of using `MessageBox` to print these results or if there is any other way to print results?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FAREEDH;Initial Catalog=DeakinsTrade;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried different methods but it never worked.. I am really stuck. If you want more details, let me know. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: @marc_s How do I add the fields and print them out using MessageBox..I triedd .ExecuteReader() and while statement..but I did not how to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a datagridview control to show multiple rows and try this code and rename it what you want and replace this `YourDataGridVeiwName` from the name you set for datagridview control and try below code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=FAREEDH;Initial Catalog=DeakinsTrade;Integrated Security=True";
        string query = "SELECT ProductName FROM Products;";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {

              DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
              sda.Fill(dt);
              YourDataGridVeiwName.DataSource= dt;
             }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `SqlDataReader` and **iterate over** the rows returned, extract what you need from each row, and then display that to the enduser.

I modified your code a bit, to make it safer (`using` blocks!), and I modified the query to return only the product name (assuming you have that) since you cannot really display a *whole row* in a message box....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=FAREEDH;Initial Catalog=DeakinsTrade;Integrated Security=True";
        string query = "SELECT ProductName FROM Products;";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while (reader.Read()) 
               {
                    string productName = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(0);
                    MessageBox("Product is: " + productName);
               }

               reader.Close();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried use different MessageBox's to display a lot of the fields but it preinted the fields in different MessageBox. Is it not possible to print in the same Box. Is there anyother way? I am confused

Comment: I am trying print out all the rows from the SQL table. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Then you need to put them into something that **supports** multiple rows - like a **grid** (not a message box.....)

Comment: THAT REALLLY MAKESS SENSEEEE>..hahaha THANK YOUUUUU..If you want to edit your answerr with Grids..I will mark that as an answer